# Certificate expired, renewed. Got now this error: server did not recognize the value of http Header SOAP Action

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint, soap

I have an secured webservice with a certificate. These webservice was always working, but after the certificate was expired and renewed, it doesnt work anymore. I have a test webservice tool to check if the webservice is working or not. When I test it, one of the webmethods is working and the other gives me an error.

When I enter the webservice url in the browser on the local server where the webservice is running, it is accessable. I can see all the webmethods in this webservice.

1 webmethod "HelloWorld" is working.

1 other webmethod "copyIntoItems" is not working. The webmethod "copyIntoItems" webmethod copies a file to a SharePoint portal. It was always working and nothing changed (only the certificate renewed). This webmethod returns the following error:

**server did not recognize the value of http Header SOAP Action.**

I have checked where the old certificate was located. It was located on the local computer in the folder personal. I have removed the old one and imported the new one. Thats it.

Can someone tell me why I got this problem?

[image soap test tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vi8U6.jpg)